# localStorage.setItem can't store strings of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html, local-storage

I used to have a script that used `GM_setValue()` to store a chunk of html from a page, and load it on another page.
So:

```
var data = '<div id="test">testing</div>';
GM_setValue("test", data);
alert(GM_getValue("test", "failed"));
```

would alert `<div id="test">testing</div>`.

Recently we moved away from the GM API in favor of jQuery and HTML5, and replaced GM_setValue GM_getValue with functions like:

```
function $setVal(name, value){
 localStorage.setItem(name, value);
 return false;
}
function $getVal(name, notset){
 return localStorage.getItem(name) || notset;
}
```

The problem is now that it can no longer store strings of HTML like the GM equivs can. With the new functions in place, the example script would alert failed.

i've tried escaping with regex's, and escaping with `escape()`, but I'm having no luck.

Anyone know what to do?

EDIT: the awkward thing is, this actually seems to work fine. just not in the scope I need it to. I have a text box that is simply evaled as javascript on submission for testing, and when I call the function from there, it works, however chucks an error when called by the code.
Thanks you for your help, but it doesn't actually seem to be a problem the same way I thought it was, sorry.

Comment: Cannot reproduce `var s = '<div id="test">testing</div>'; sessionStorage.setItem('foo', s); s === sessionStorage.getItem('foo'); // true`

Comment: he's using localstorage not session storage

Comment: @VoronoiPotato it's the same result with either for me

Comment: give me a min and I'll whip up a fiddle.

Comment: yeah it works for me, I can only assume he's doing something REALLY weird in his real code, so I used encodeURI

Comment: ahh, it looks like it was what I was using to test that wasn't working, $setVal(testa,  testb) || alert("failed test"); alerts a fail whether or not it did. okay, thanks, it still doen't work in the scope of my code, but at least I know it's possible now, thanks.

Comment: Note that the `getItem(...) || notset` shortcut will fail if the value is set, but falsy, i.e. `$setVal('foo', '');` and then `$getVal('foo', 'uh-oh')` will result in `"uh-oh"`.

Comment: I know, that was a typo in the hurry. I fixed it already.

Comment: Since `getItem` always returns a string, the only scenario where the `||` fails should be `""` (empty string). It may or may not be intended, but it certainly is not the same as "not set".

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the HTML like so

```
var html = '<div id=\"test\">testing</div>';

localStorage.setItem("Foo", html);
```

Put `\` before the `"`.

EDIT:

I just tried the following (in Firefox as it was open in front of me), and it works fine:

```
var html = '<div id="test">testing</div>';

localStorage.setItem("Foo", html);

console.log(localStorage.getItem("Foo"));
```

Just tried it in Chrome and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use encodeURI to store, then decodeURI to retrieve

```
localStorage.setItem('html',encodeURI('<div id="test">testing</div>'))
localStorage.getItem('html')
"%3Cdiv%20id=%22test%22%3Etesting%3C/div%3E"
decodeURI(localStorage.getItem('html'))
  "<div id="test">testing</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the *Storage* of generic data by converting it to [***JSON***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON) and back. This works for everything that supports conversion to *JSON (String, Number, most Objects, Boolean, etc)*.

```
var Mem = (function (localStorage, JSON) {
    return {
        'set': function (key, value) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        },
        'get': function (key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        },
        'del': function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
                localStorage.removeItem(arguments[i]);
        }
    };
}(window.localStorage, window.JSON)); // protect references
```

And usage

```
Mem.set('foo', 0);
Mem.set('bar', '0');
Mem.set('baz', false);
Mem.get('foo'); // Number 0
Mem.get('bar'); // String "0"
Mem.get('baz'); // Bool false
Mem.del('foo', 'bar', 'baz'); // cleanup
```

So for your example

```
var data = '<div id="test">testing</div>';
Mem.set('test', data);
console.log(Mem.get('test') === data); // true
Mem.del('test'); // cleanup
```